# How to implement SMS and Email service in alexa?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am trying to implement a SMS and email service in alexa and using PHP, Jquery to acheive the task. I am very new to the technology and after serching to lot of website, I am lost somewhere and unable to start. Please let me know any reference regarding the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using [Amazon SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/sns/) to accomplish both tasks (SMS and email). You can set up a topic, subscribe a user to it, and send these notifications. The easiest path forward is to use Lambda for your Alexa Skill endpoint, and if you use Nodejs, here is an example of how to do it:

```
'use strict';
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

var playerSMS = (function () {
    var sns = new AWS.SNS();

return {
    sendTopicSubscribeRequest: function (phoneKey, callback) {
        var topicName = {
          Name: phoneKey.toString()
        };

        sns.createTopic(topicName, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                callback('errorCreatingTopicARN'); 
            } else {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // successful response
                console.log('data.TopicArn = ' + data.TopicArn);
                var topicArn = data.TopicArn;
                console.log('topicArn = ' + topicArn);

                // now create the display name, which is a required attribute               
                var params = {
                  AttributeName: 'DisplayName',
                  TopicArn: topicArn, 
                  AttributeValue: 'My text'
                };                  
                sns.setTopicAttributes(params, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                    } else {
                        console.log('data = ' + JSON.stringify(data) ); // successful response


                        // now subscribe the phone number to the topic                          
                        var subscribeInputParams = {
                          Protocol: 'sms', 
                          TopicArn: topicArn, 
                          Endpoint: '1-' + phoneKey.toString() //'1-425-890-8000'
                        };

                        sns.subscribe(subscribeInputParams, function(err, data) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                            } else {
                                console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // successful response
                            };
                            callback(topicArn); 
                        });                             
                    };
                });                                                                         
            };
        });         
    },


    publishSMS: function (incomingARN, incomingMessage, callback) {
        sns.publish({
            Message: incomingMessage,
            TopicArn: incomingARN
        }, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.stack);
                console.log(err, 'publishSMS function did not successfully complete.');
                var success = false;
            }

            if (data) {
                console.log('publishSMS function successfully sent a text to ' + incomingARN);
                var success = true;                 
            };

            // delay callback for 1 second to allow texts to arrive in order
            setTimeout(callBackAfterDelay, 200);

            function callBackAfterDelay() {
                callback(success);
            };      
        });
    }       
};      

})();
module.exports = playerSMS;
```

Invoke via:

```
playerSMS.sendTopicSubscribeRequest(Player.phoneNumberGoesHere, function (topicArn) {
    if (!topicArn) {
        speechText = 'Hmm, there was a problem getting that set up. Please try again later.';               
    } else { // successfully created Topic ARN and sent the subscription request
        newLoadedPlayer.data.TopicARN = topicArn;
        speechText = 'You are now set up to receive texts when you ask for them. What would you like to do now?';
    };  
    Player.save(session, function () {
        response.ask(speechText, repromptTextToSay);    
    });         
});
```

And:

```
playerSMS.publishSMS(ARNtoSend, textToSend, function (success) {
    // Do something here upon success or failure
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use twilio which works pretty good with alexa https://github.com/krvarma/Amazon-Echo-and-Twilio Getting an email from the user by telling it to alexa in my opinion is impossible for now. Alexa doesnt convert all what you says to the right text, additional problem are special characters as - _ @

Answer (score 0):

Though there seems to be an answer already utilizing Amazon, if you wanted an alternative emailer you could use https://www.sendgrid.com for the emailing, and https://www.twilio.com for SMS, MMS, Voice and more. Twilio also has their own transcription and recording services as well as extra modules available including tying into IBM watson. Might be worth a look for you.